# How do you add a JPanel onto another JPanel that has graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

Basically what im trying to do is to add a JPanel onto another JPanel that has painted graphics on it using the paintComponent() method. But the JPanel I am trying to add is not shown because it is covered up by the JPanel w/ Graphics on it.

How can I make it so that when I add the JPanel to the one w/ graphics it will show the JPanel in the front instead of being covered up by the Graphics?

All answers are appreciated! :)

If you need the code just tell me and I will gladly put it on here.

Alright here is the code:

```
package javavideogame;
public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable
{

 public Game(MainCharacter character)
 {
     setLayout(null);
     setFocusable(true);

 }


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(ground, 0, 0, this);
     g.drawImage(character.getImage(), character.getX(), character.getY(), this);
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.drawRect(10, 10, character.getMaxHealth(), 10);
     g.fillRect(10, 10, character.getHealth(), 10);
     g.dispose();
 }

 public void getInventoryScreen()
 {
     Main.inv = new Inventory();
     Main.game.add(Main.inv);
 }
}
```

And here is the code for the JPanel that I'm adding to the Game JPanel

```
public class Inventory extends JPanel
{
     public Inventory()
     {
         setLayout(null);
         setSize(400, 300);
         setBackground(Color.BLACK);
         addKeyListener(this);
         setFocusable(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: A SSCCE should always be posted so we don't have to guess what you may or may not be doing. Also, many times when creating a SSCCE you will find the problem so you won't even need to post a question.

Comment: I don't think you should dispose of the Graphics object that is passed into your paintComponent method.  I'm not sure what effect this will have, but it doesn't look good.  OTOH, yes, do dispose a Graphics object that you've created yourself after you're done using it, but not the one passed into paint or paintComponent since you didn't create it.

Comment: @Hovercraft your way worked! I took out the g.dispose(); and it worked completely! I just had that in there because I was sort of going by what a tutorial said about it. But Thanks!

Comment: As a side comment, it's a poor naming decision to call something `getAnything(...)` and have it `void` and actually setting something. I would recommend calling it `initInventoryScreen()`, as a matter of good practice.

Comment: Yeah the tutorial is right if you create the Graphics object say from a BufferedImage. Otherwise you risk running out of system resources. But the Graphics object passed into your paintComponent method was created by the Graphics subsystem (I think), and may be used to paint the component's borders and children. Since your added JPanel is a child component, it may not be painted if you dispose the Graphics object.  To any expert out there -- please correct any incorrect assumptions I may be making here -- thanks!

Comment: @glowcoder Yea I think ill start using it that way. I just thought of a name really quick though so thats what I came up with. All of my other getStuff() actually returns things though.

Answer (score 1):

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent(...) method. My guess is that you are overriding the paint() method.

Read this section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). Because you are overriding the wrong method, you end up painting the children first and then the custom painting is done on top.

If you need more help than post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder: java.awt and javax.swing don't mix well.  When you're painting stuff on one panel AND trying to add a JPanel to it, you are bound to run into problems somewhere.  A far better solution is to have 2 different JPanels, one for your graphics, and one for your inventory.

Something like this:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //will hold BOTH panels
JPanel gamePanel = new Game(myCharacter); //declare game panel
JPanel inventoryPanel = new Inventory(); //declare inventory panel

//set up some layout
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

//add the graphics panel, then add the inventory
mainPanel.add(gamePanel);
mainPanel.add(inventoryPanel);
```

This will keep your swing and awt components from mixing and save you a lot of headaches.